# Use Ember js on script sharp

Tags: script#

I want to write the following line with script sharp:

```
App.SP = SP = Ember.Object.extend({
init: function (lineV, lineH, resourceMethod){...
```

Is this possible? how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, every script framework comes with its own variant pattern of defining classes, and script# doesn't support all possible variants... so you can write a c# class called SP, with an Init method, and expect the EmberJS way of defining classes is the result.

What you could do is define classes for Ember.Object with an extend method that takes a dictionary, populate the dictionary with a bunch of name/value pairs, for example "init" with a value set to a delegate to a static method.

Example (this is just a start, which I am sure will require tweaking and more reworking if you continue this path):

In an import library:

```
namespace EmberApi {

    [Imported, ScriptNamespace("Ember"), ScriptName("Object")]
    public static class EmberObject {

        public static object Extend(Dictionary<string, object> nameValuePairs) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And in your code:

```
public static void App {

    static App() {
        Dictionary<string, object> members = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        members["init"] = Init;

        object sp = EmberObject.Extend(members);
    }

    public static void Init(int lineV, int lineH, string resourceMethod) { ... }
}
```

So I think it is possible, but you're loosing a bunch of value prop, which is to write your code like c#.

A better fit is to be able to consume existing APIs/frameworks, but write your own code as regular c# classes, that leverage the script# pattern of transforming those type constructs into script.

If there are suggestions on the pattern itself, more than welcome, esp. since there is thought on making the script# pattern considerably lighter weight going into the future.

Comment: I'm using ember for a minor part of my app, but it's very usefulle, I'm relaying on the observer mechanizm to make all my models synchronized to changes of one another.

Answer (score 1):

In answering another question, a new approach came to mind, that I'll share as an idea with some potential, in case you're still interested, or for others down the road.

The compiler assumes a certain runtime contract (one fulfilled by mscorlib.js) which includes APIs like Type.registerClass and other related methods. One approach to working with other frameworks that come with their own patterns for defining types is to simply reimplement mscorlib.js such that the methods like registerClass serve as a bridge to the other library.